# Better way of logic loop while button is pressed?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

So I have a button on a WinRT UserControl that I want to increase or decrease a integer value (CurrentValue) while you hold down the button.

I ended up with this implementation below, which works but does not look to good or is it okay?

I searched for an event to use but I got stuck using click and setting the button.clickmode to press.

I use the bool _increasePushed to track if already pushed in so I don't get multiple event triggers.

```
    private bool _increasePushed;
    private const int PushDelay = 200;

    private async void ButtonIncreaseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button == null) return;

        if (_increasePushed)
        {
            return;
        }

        _increasePushed = true;

        while (button.IsPressed)
        {
            CurrentValue++;
            await Task.Delay(PushDelay);
        }

        _increasePushed = false;
    }
```

XAML on UserControl

```
    <Button x:Name="buttonIncrease" Content="Bla bla"
            Click="ButtonIncreaseClick" ClickMode="Press" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way would be to use a [RepeatButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.repeatbutton) which does exactly what you are trying to replicate. It has a Delay property to wait for the first repeated click as well as an Interval property that controls how often the Click event is raised.